# Visual Studio Extension subscribe to a debugger event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I'm developing a visual studio extension and now I'm facing a problem:
How do I subscribe to a Brake Point, i.e. every time the debugger catches the Brake Point, I would like to perform some action.

I can split this single problem into 2 problems:

1. How do I fire a function without pressing anything (I understand that the event should do this)

2. What function should I call to see the breakpoints (make my function fire)

(Don't see any reason to put any code because this is a HOWTO question and for real I don't have what to show)

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DTE.Events.DebuggerEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dispdebuggerevents_event?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) and [DTE.Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debugger?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to receive notifications of a break point and get information about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to read events correctly? I thought of background worker that will always monitor for an event enum (brakepoknt in my case), however i think that its too resource consuming. Thanks!

Comment: @NickChernuha You just subscribe to events like debuggerEvents.OnEnterRunMode += OnEnterRunMode and in the handler perform your work. Everything in UI thread.